# Настройка пк с dahdi в качестве voip шлюза

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Возможно ли настроить пк с dahdi картой на борту в качестве некого воип шлюза? Для того что бы в дальнейшем звонить через него используя asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Да, если у вас есть соответствующая пара плата-подключение. То есть E1 плюс какая-нибудь TE410 или похожая. Или ISDN S/T плюс какая-нибудь B23x.

Можно, вероятно, и с аналоговым подключением и соответствующей карточкой, но аналог — то такое... Возни и проблем часто много. Для этого случая, IMHO, лучше взять внешний FXO-девайс, его хотя бы перезагрузить менее болезненно.